# A -> IO B to IO (A -> B)

Tags: haskell

I want to convert a function `A -> IO B` to `IO (A -> B)`, knowing that there is only a finite number of possible values of `A`. At the moment I just do

```
 convert :: (A -> IO B) -> IO (A -> B)
 convert f = do
     b1 <- f a1
     b2 <- f a2
     ...
     let f' a1 = b1
         f' a2 = b2
         ...
     return f'
```

However I'm not satisfied with the amount of code this requires.

Comment: Is that really what you want? You’ll execute the side-effects of the argument once for each *possible* value of `A`, even for those that do not occur.

Comment: This is an unusual transformation.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, my use case is that `A` is a chess piece and `B` is its icon.

Comment: I have to ask - why does a function that takes a piece `A` to an icon `B` have the type `A -> IO B` and not just `A -> B`?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor, by icon I mean an image, stored in a file. `A -> IO B` is the loading of that file. `A -> B` is a cache of results of `A -> IO B`.

Comment: That's a very handy function that I've used myself several times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A slightly souped-up version of Joachim's answer, that uses `Data.Map` to perform the lookup faster. I'll be using the TupleSections pragma as well.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import Data.Map
import Control.Monad
```

For added neatness, assume that your `Piece` type can be given `Ord`, `Bounded` and `Enum` instances.

```
data Piece = Knight | Bishop | Rook deriving (Ord,Bounded,Enum,Show)
```

and define the useful `enumerate` function

```
enumerate :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
enumerate = [minBound..maxBound]
```

Now you can do

```
convert :: (Monad m, Bounded a, Enum a, Ord a) => (a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)
convert f = do
    memo <- sequence [liftM (a,) (f a)  | a <- enumerate]
    return (fromList memo!)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a list `values :: [A]`, and `A` has an `Eq`-Instance, this would work:

```
convert :: (A -> IO B) -> IO (A -> B)
convert f = do
  lookupTable <- sequence [ (\b -> (a,b)) `fmap` f a | a <- values]
  return $ (\a -> fromJust (lookup a lookupTable))
```

As other have noted, if you don’t mind the additional type class requirements for `A`, you can use maps or hashmaps to speed up the lookup.

Also, from your use-case description, it seems that you are loading static data from a file that comes with your program. Depending on the environment where your final program runs (e.g. guaranteed that the files exist and are not changing), this might be a valid use for `unsafePerformIO` to simply define `A -> B` as a top-level function. Alternatively there are ways to include binary blobs in the compile source.

Comment: I really dislike this, for it's use of `Maybe`, but then I suspect this is the best I'll get..

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I'd like to add that I'd call `convert` only once and then use the function it produces to make lookups in pure code. This will ensure that you read `B`s only once. A slight improvement would be to use `Data.Map` instead of a list to get a bit faster lookups. And if you want to avoid `fromJust`, you could have/load some default `B` value and use `fromMaybe theDefault` instead of `fromJust`.

Comment: Unless you have a language that allows you to express that `values` really contains all values (maybe in Agda you can do that), you will have partialness of one form of the other (possibly using a default value as a backup).

Comment: There's the [`universe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-0.4.0.3) package which indicates finite domains by fiat. I also remember a blog post somewhere (perhaps Russel O'Connor's blog) which had a typeclass that was likely impossible to instantiate for infinite types. Either of these would justify using something unsafe like `fromJust`.

Comment: Actually it was probably Martin Escardo's work, but I can't find it.

Comment: And it would probably not be impossible in Haskell, if definitions were allowed to be partial.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė you cannot get this conversion for arbitrary functions, and there is a theoretical reason for that. But you can do that for arbitrary monads in Haskell using pairs. Everyone here suggested only sugar to expose function-like interface to a list of pairs built for known inputs.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, I'll mention that the [countable package on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/countable-0.1) makes this possible by providing the `Finite` type class. You define something like

```
instance Finite Piece where
  allValues = [Pawn, Knight, Bishop, Rook, Queen, King]
```

then you have

```
assemble :: (Finite a, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)
```

which will specialise to precisely what you need.

Looking at the source, it seems that it uses an association list, so it would be slow if your type was large. Plus, it defines some orphan instances of `Foldable` and `Traversable` and `Eq` (!) for functions, which some may regard as distasteful.

Answer (score 0):

You have function `f :: A -> IO B`  and you have `g :: IO A`, 
you use your `convert` function with `Applicative` `<*> :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` as

```
fg :: IO a -> (a ->IO B) -> IO B
fg g f = (convert f) <*>  g
```

But you can just use monad `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`,

```
fg :: IO a -> (a ->IO B) -> IO B
fg g f = g >>= f
```

Comment: I most definitely do not use my convert like that. Instead I do `pureF <- convert ioF` in my `main` and then pass `pureF` around in my pure functions.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your position. But in case `pureF <- convert ioF` you have unsafe functions instead of having unsafe data.

Comment: There is nothing unsafe about this. I merely perform the side effects before using their results.

Answer (score 0):

Your function signature permits any function `a->m b` on input, yet inside you assume a specific range of values. `convert` is not as polymorphic as the signature seems to declare.

What you have done is created a Map from a to b, then made a pure function that looks up a pure value in that map. Here's why:

What you are asking for is similar to implementing [tensorial strength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_monad) `strength :: (Monad m) => (a, m b) -> m (a, b)` for a monoidal category (C, ⊗, I) - given a binary relation ⊗ in category C and a monad m, convert a ⊗ m b to m (a ⊗ b). When this is possible for a binary relationship that meets certain requirements, the monad is strong. In Haskell all monads are strong, if tensorial product a ⊗ b is chosen to be a pair `(a, b)`: `strength (a, mb) = mb >>= return . (a,)`. Yet, here you are attempting to do the same for a binary relationship `->`. Unfortunately, `a -> b` cannot be chosen to be a tensor product, because it is not a bi-functor - it is contravariant in `a`. So what you want cannot be accomplished for arbitrary functions.

What is different in your case, is that essentially you built all pairs `(a,b)`. The amount of code, therefore, can be reduced if you explicitly enumerate all possible pairs of `a` and `b`, for example by building a `m (Map a b)`. The others here offered nice sugars exposing "function-like" interfaces, but they are merely lookups in the map.

Comment: It seems to me that since `->` is, as you point out, not even the right sort of thing to be a tensor product, the discussion of `strength` is not really relevant.

Comment: @BenMillwood It seems to me that it should be clear from the discussion of `strength` why what the topic starter wants is not even achievable for arbitrary functions, and in what form it is achievable.

Comment: @BenMillwood also, what the others suggested is a sugar around a plain lookup, or map from known keys to precomputed values.