# Monads: Determining if an arbitrary transformation is possible

Tags: haskell, monads

There are [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890408/a-io-b-to-io-a-b) a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342863/unsequence-monad-function-within-haskell) of questions here about whether or not certain transformations of types that involve Monads are possible.

For instance, it's possible to make a function of type `f :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`, but impossible to make a function of type `g :: Monad m => m [a] -> [m a]` as a proper antifunction to the former. (IE: `f . g = id`)

I want to understand what rules one can use to determine if a function of that type can or cannot be constructed, and why these types cannot be constructed if they disobey these rules.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper antifunction"? That composition with both orders result in the identity, i.e. the inverse? Your question is imho very interesting a starting point might be wadler's theorems for free (http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf) that derives rules that polymorphic functions must obey (as an implication of being polymorphic). Maybe these theorems could be in contradiction with the monad laws for specific signatures?

Comment: @uberwach yes, exactly, inverse/antifunction are often used interchangeably in linear algebra. I'll make it clearer...

Comment: Sometimes the impossibility proof can be derived from logical considerations via Curry-Howard e.g. (shameless plugs) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267848/turning-a-mb-into-ma-b/27267992#27267992 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141972/how-to-apply-higher-order-function-to-an-effectful-function-in-haskell/24142893#24142893

Comment: More on Curry-Howard: the logic related to monads is called Lax Logic, and is decidable (via e.g. cut-elimination of its sequent calculus). I think that you can only build functions whose type corresponds to a theorem of such logic. So, given a (mono)type you can decide whether it's a theorem in Lax Logic and know whether you can implement it for any monad.

Comment: You may want to read ["Representing Applicatives"](http://comonad.com/reader/2013/representing-applicatives/), and Gershom Bazerman's other posts to the Comonad.Reader blog, which mentions that all representable functors are *distributive*: `distribute :: (Functor f, Representable g) => f (g a) -> g (f a)`

Comment: Beware that antifunction has a different definition, as the morphisms in Set* by Vaughn Pratt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that I've always thought about monads is that a value of type `Monad m => m a` is some program of type `m` that executes and produces an `a`. The [monad laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) reinforce this notion by thinking of composition of these programs as "do thing one then do thing two", and produce some sort of combination of the results.

- **Right unit** Taking a program and just returning its value should
  be the same as just running the original program.

  ```
  m >>= return = m
  ```
- **Left unit** If you create a simple program that just returns a value,
  and then pass that value to a function that creates a new program, then
  the resulting program should just be as if you called the function on the
  value.

  ```
  return x >>= f = f x
  ```
- **Associativity** If you execute a program `m`, feed its result into a function `f` that produces another program, and then feed that result into a third function `g` that also produces a program, then this is identical to creating a new function that returns a program based on feeding the result of `f` into `g`, and feeding the result of `m` into it.

  ```
  (m >>= f) >>= g  =  m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
  ```

Using this intuition about a "program that creates a value" can come to some conclusions about what it means for the functions that you've provided in your examples.

1. `Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]` Deviating from the intuitive definition of what this function should do is hard: Execute each program in sequence and collect the results. This produces another program that produces a list of results.
2. `Monad m => m [a] -> [m a]` This doesn't really have a clear intuitive definition, since it's a program that produces a list. You can't create a list without getting access to the resulting values which in this case means executing a program. Certain monads, that have a clear way to extract a value from a program, and provide some variant of `m a -> a`, like the `State` monad, can have sane implementations of some function like this. It would have to be application specific though. Other monads, like `IO`, you cannot escape from.
3. `Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)` This also doesn't really have a clear intuitive definition. Here you have a function `f` that produces a program of type `m b`, but you're trying to return a function of type `m (a -> b)`. Based on the `a`, `f` creates completely different programs with different executing semantics. You cannot encompass these variations in a single program of type `m (a -> b)`, even if you can provide a proper mapping of `a -> b` in the programs resulting value.

This intuition doesn't really encompass the idea behind monads completely. For example, the monadic context of a list doesn't really behave like a program.

Comment: `Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)` can be done if you know something about `a` -- for example that it is finite. The [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0/docs/Data-Universe-Instances-Reverse.html#t:Traversable) package provides `sequence :: (Finite a, Ord a, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)` (via a `Traversable` instance for functions).

Comment: Sure, it can also be done for monads for which you understand the environment, like `Reader`.

Answer (score 2):

Something easy to remember is : "you can't escape from a Monad" (it's kind of design for it). Transforming `m [a]` to `[m a]` is a form of escape, so you can't.

On the other hand you can easily create a Monad from something (using `return`) so *traversing* (`[m a] -> m [a]`) is usually possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at ["Monad laws"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads), monad only constrain you to define a composition function but not reverse function.

In the first example you can compose the list elements.
In the second one `Monad m => m [a] -> [m a]`, you cannot split an action into multiple actions ( action composition is not reversible).

#### Example:

Let's say you have to read 2 values.

```
s1 <- action
s2 <- action
```

Doing so, action result s2 depends by the side effect made by s1.
You can bind these 2 actions in 1 action to be executed in the same order, but you cannot split them and execute action from s2 without s1 made the side effect needed by the second one.

Comment: I see what you mean by sequence, but how can I use that to determine, for instance, if a function of type `Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)` is possible?

Comment: I'm new to Haskell, and i didn't fully understand the Monads but i think it makes non-sense to can decompose a function and take out the action from it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, and much too informal for my linking, but nevertheless I have a few interesting observations that won't fit into a comment. First, let's consider this function you refer to:

```
f :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

This signature is in fact stronger than it needs to be.  The current generalization of this is the `sequenceA` function from `Data.Traversable`:

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) -> t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

...which doesn't need the full power of `Monad`, and can work with any `Traversable` and not just lists.

Second: the fact that `Traversable` only requires `Applicative` is I think really significant to this question, because applicative computations have a "list-like" structure.  Every applicative computation can be rewritten to have the form `f <$> a1 <*> ... <*> an` for some `f`.  Or, informally, every applicative computation can be seen as a list of actions `a1, ... an` (heterogeneous on the result type, homogeneous in the functor type), plus an n-place function to combine their results.

If we look at `sequenceA` through this lens, all it does is choose an `f` built out of the appropriate nested number of list constructors:

```
sequenceA [a1, ..., an] == f <$> a1 <*> ... <*> an
    where f v1 ... vn = v1 : ... : vn : []
```

Now, I haven't had the chance to try and prove this yet, but my conjectures would be the following:

1. Mathematically speaking at least, `sequenceA` has a [*left inverse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses) in [free applicative functors](http://www.paolocapriotti.com/assets/applicative.pdf).  If you have a `Functor f => [FreeA f a]` and you `sequenceA` it, what you get is a list-like structure that contains those computations and a combining function that makes a list out of their results.  I suspect however that it's not possible to write such a function in Haskell (`unSequenceFreeA :: (Traversable t, Functor f) => FreeA f (t a) -> Maybe (t (Free f a))`), because you can't pattern match on the structure of the combining function in the `FreeA` to tell that it's of the form `f v1 ... vn = v1 : ... : vn : []`.
2. `sequenceA` doesn't have a right inverse in a free applicative, however, because the combining function that produces a list out of the results from the `a1, ... an` actions may do anything; for example, return a constant list of arbitrary length (unrelated to the computations that the free applicative value performs).
3. Once you move to non-free applicative functors, there will no longer be a left inverse for `sequenceA`, because the non-free applicative functor's equations translate into cases where you can no longer tell apart which of two `t (f a)` "action lists" was the source for a given `f (t a)` "list-producing action."

Comment: I'm not asking for a specific reason for one example, I'm asking for general rules for working this out, and for Monads specifically, not Applicatives.

Comment: @AJFarmar: `Applicative` is a superclass of `Monad`, so statements about `Applicative` are certainly relevant to `Monad`.  And I don't think the right approach here is that you work this out directly from some general rules: rather, you use [*lemmas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_%28mathematics%29) that follow from general rules. Part of the process of learning to apply general rules is to learn a bunch of lemmas that allow you to recognize specific situations where the rules apply. And there's no shortcut there—you have to read a lot.