# Transformation of (a -> IO b) to IO (a -> b)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, io-monad, lifting

I have several data types in an IO context like:

```
a :: IO String
b :: IO FilePath
c :: String -> IO String
```

I want to put them all together in one data object like:

```
data Configdata = Configdata String FilePath (String -> String)
```

So I don't have to get each value for its own out of the IO context, but just out of `IO Configdata`.

The critical point where I don't have a solution is how I can transform `String -> IO String` to `IO (String -> String)`.
Hoogle doesn't give me any functions which are capable of doing this.

I am not sure if it's maybe even not possible, since the input of the function is possibly infinite.

Does someone have a solution or an explanation why it's not possible?
I know that using a list instead of a function is an option, but I would prefer using a function if possible.

Comment: That's not really compatible. In `String -> IO String`, the IO computation can depend on the argument, in `IO (String -> String)` it cannot.

Comment: @Bergi stated it perfectly. This is the key difference between Applicative and Monad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18890408 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed this is not possible. Consider the function:

```
import Acme.Missiles

boo :: String -> IO String
boo "cute" = return "Who's a nice kitty?"
boo "evil" = launchMissiles >> return "HTML tags lea͠ki̧n͘g fr̶ǫm ̡yo​͟ur eye͢s̸ ̛l̕ik͏e liq​uid pain"
```

Now, if it were possible to transform this to `IO (String -> String)`, it would have to execute [all possible `IO` actions for any input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) before returning the pure `String -> String` function. IOW, even if you only planned to use the function for kitten-watching purposes, it would entail nuclear holocaust.

Nevertheless, it may well be possible to do this *for your specific application*. In particular, if you know the function will only ever be called for a predetermined set of strings, you can pre-query them from `IO` and store the results in a map, which can then be indexed purely.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

puh :: IO (String -> String)
puh = fmap ((Map.!) . Map.fromList) . forM ["cute"] $ \q -> do
       res <- boo q
       return (q, res)
```

Of course, this may not be feasible performance-wise.

Comment: If there is a predetermined set of strings, it probably makes sense to make a small custom type with one value per string in the set. Then the universe package can give you [`sequenceA :: (Foo -> IO String) -> IO (Foo -> String)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0/docs/Data-Universe-Instances-Reverse.html#t:Traversable), which has the behavior you describe of creating a `Map` and indexing into it.